# flutter image_picker stops showing permissions dialog

Tags: flutter, flutter-image-picker

Is there a way to force `image_picker` to always show permissions dialog?
Currently, after denying permissions, it stops showing it.

[image]

Comment: Which code do you currently use to display the picker?

Comment: Sample image_picker app. The line that picks images and shows the permissions prompt is `await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)`